# Reactor based polling is not terminating

Tags: java, project-reactor

Intention is to poll a certain number of times until I receive a particular response. Here is the piece of code I have compiled:

```
Mono.defer(() -> webClient.getResponse())
        // repeat GET call after every 500 ms
        .repeatWhen(repeat -> repeat.delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(500)))
        .repeat(4) // max repeat attempts
        .takeUntil(response -> response.equals("1"))
        //.retryWhen(Retry.max(3))
        .log()
        .subscribe(response -> {
            System.out.println("response received: " + response);
        });
```

But, there's a problem. It is not stopping at all. I was expecting it to run 4 times and exit.

```
12:54:54.527 [parallel-7] INFO  reactor.Flux.TakeUntil.1 - onNext(2)
response received: 2
12:54:55.034 [parallel-8] INFO  reactor.Flux.TakeUntil.1 - onNext(2)
response received: 2
12:54:55.540 [parallel-9] INFO  reactor.Flux.TakeUntil.1 - onNext(2)
response received: 2
12:54:56.045 [parallel-10] INFO  reactor.Flux.TakeUntil.1 - onNext(2)
response received: 2
12:54:56.551 [parallel-1] INFO  reactor.Flux.TakeUntil.1 - onNext(2)
response received: 2
12:54:57.057 [parallel-2] INFO  reactor.Flux.TakeUntil.1 - onNext(2)
response received: 2
12:54:57.563 [parallel-3] INFO  reactor.Flux.TakeUntil.1 - onNext(2)
response received: 2
.......
```

Answer (score 1):

`repeat(int n)` runs the flux n number of times. But in your case, you've used `repeatWhen` before that, and it produces an infinite flux. That's why your flux does not ends anymore.

If you want to retry subscription until you receive the right value, you can use [retryWhen](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#retryWhen-reactor.util.retry.Retry-) function. It takes a retry configuration as input, to limit the number of retries, specifies delays between retrys, etc. In your case, you can:

1. Fail the stream if you do not receive the right value
2. Append a *retryWhen* operation to retry subscription.

Let's illustrate it with an example:

```java
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.util.retry.Retry;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import static java.lang.System.nanoTime;

public class RetryWhen {

    /**
     * Emit a decreased value on each subscription
     * @param initial First value to emit
     */
    static Mono<Integer> countdown(int initial) {
        var current = new AtomicInteger(initial);
        var t0 = nanoTime();
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> current.getAndDecrement())
                .doOnNext(i -> System.out.printf(
                        "Emit %d at %d ms%n",
                        i, (int)((nanoTime() - t0) * 1e-6)
                ));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var source = countdown(4);
        // raise an error if value is different than one.
        var oneOrError = source.filter(i -> i == 1)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("bad value")));

        // Retry 4 times maximum. Each retry is spaced by ~ 500 ms
        var retried = oneOrError.retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(4, Duration.ofMillis(500)));

        var result = retried.block();
        System.out.println("Result: "+result);
    }
}
```

The above program produces:

```
Emit 4 at 173 ms
Emit 3 at 696 ms
Emit 2 at 1198 ms
Emit 1 at 1699 ms
Result: 1
```

*Notes* :

- in your case, repeatWhen produces an infinite stream, because the function you passed to it never returns an empty publisher. It causes continuous subscription to your original mono (which returns "2").
- Also, as *repeatWhen* repeat values from the **source/caller**, your `.takeUntil(response -> response.equals("1"))` statement will never be matched (it will always receive "2").

Comment: Thank you for the useful information. I want to however fire the logic inside Mono.defer() - a web resource GET call, (a) after a fixed delay of 500 ms for every repeat (b) until it returns desirable response for (c) a maximum of 4 repeats.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more obvious.

Comment: Ok, I better understand. I think you require `retryWhen`. I'll try to edit my response when I have some time.

Comment: Hi Amanin, did you get a chance to check and help me. Once again, the intention is to hit the external api repeatedly after specific interval for max N count until favourable response is received and then just continue on the current thread with other operations.

Comment: @xploreraj I have already edited my respsonse a few days ago. But I haven't thought of notifying you, sorry. Can you check my answer again ?

Comment: Thank you @amanin. I missed seeing your edit. I new retry was working on error signal, but I thought if I could achieve it with repeat, then it will be lesser code. I will try your solution.